# How to play music from url in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am gonna build Xamarin.Forms app which play music from url.

I used dependency service for each platform implementation.

`[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioSerivce))]`

`namespace xxx.Droid`
{

```
public class AudioSerivce : IAudio
{
    int clicks = 0;
    MediaPlayer player;

    public AudioSerivce()
    {
    }

    public bool Play_Pause (string url)
    {
        if (clicks == 0) {
            this.player = new MediaPlayer();
            this.player.SetDataSource(url);
            this.player.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.Music);
            this.player.PrepareAsync();
            this.player.Prepared += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.player.Start();
            };
            clicks++;
        } else if (clicks % 2 != 0) {
            this.player.Pause();
            clicks++;

        } else {
            this.player.Start();
            clicks++;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop (bool val)
    {
        this.player.Stop();
        clicks = 0;
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

and calling it

`DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().Play_Pause("https://www.searchgurbani.com/audio/sggs/1.mp3");`

If I check log, it seems everything is ok.
But I can't hear sound on android phone.
If anyone has some suggestion, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: use the MediaManager plugin: https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

Comment: @Jason
If I use that plugin, It works for iOS, but I am getting error in android.

`Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://www.searchgurbani.com/audio/sggs/1.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

From:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64218/no-video-player-really

I suspect that there may be a problem related to an incompatibility between Octane Video player and Android Emulator, are you using a emulator/simulator?

Also another suggestion is to add this permissions:

INTERNET
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

To your Android app.

If that does not work try to use another url and compare if it working with other url's.